# Cannot find type definition file for 'component-emitter'

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, tsconfig

Recently, I've been getting the error

```
error TS2688: Cannot find type definition file for 'component-emitter'.
  The file is in the program because:
    Entry point for implicit type library 'component-emitter'

error TS2688: Cannot find type definition file for 'cookie'.
  The file is in the program because:
    Entry point for implicit type library 'cookie'

error TS2688: Cannot find type definition file for 'cors'.
  The file is in the program because:
    Entry point for implicit type library 'cors'
```

for every typescript project. These packages are never referenced anywhere, and its in *all* projects. The only fix is to install all of the type definitions (which is bad for submitting PRs), or to add `"typeRoots": ["node_modules/@types"]` to every tsconfig in all projects, which is also bad for PRs. Is there any fix?